# How to prove that different linear transformation on the same element will produce different elements?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove that:

> Suppose $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\cdots,\sigma_s$are different linear transformations in linear space $V$, there must exist an element $a\in V$, s.t. $\sigma_1 a,\sigma_2 a\cdots,\sigma_s a$ are different from each other?

Comment: What do you know about the set $\{ a\in V : \sigma_i a = \sigma_j a\}$?

Answer (score 1):

How it is formulated, in full generality, the claim is false.

Counterexample:

Let $V=(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$ and let
$$\sigma_1(x,y)=(x,0)\qquad \sigma_2(x,y)=(0,0)\qquad \sigma_3(x,y)=(x-y,0)$$

The elements of $V$ are $v_0=(0,0), v_1=(1,0), v_2=(0,1), v_3=(1,1)$

$\sigma_i(v_0)=0\qquad \forall i$

$\sigma_1(v_1)=(1,0)=\sigma_3(v_1)$

$\sigma_2(v_2)=(0,0)=\sigma_1(v_2)$

$\sigma_2(v_3)=(0,0)=\sigma_3(v_3)$

Nonetheless $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2\neq\sigma_3$

The key point is that the field used here is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

In particular, here one can express $V$ as the union of $\ker(\sigma_i-\sigma_j)$. This is possible because $V$ is finite.

In many cases, for istance for real vector spaces, one cannot have that $V$ is a finite union of sub-spaces of dimension strictly smaller than $V$, and using this hypothesis one can easily proof the claim.